# How to make a block of matrices from large matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have a 256x256 matrix from that I want to create block of 8x8 matrices. I have a below code which shows just one block i want all the blocks then subtract a number from each element of the matrix. When i do the subtract 128 from each element it doesn't show negative values rather showing only 0.

```
[x,y] = size(M);

for i=1:8
   for j=1:8
      k(i,j) = M(i,j);
   end
end

disp(k);

for a=1:size(k)
   for b=1:size(k)
     A(a,b) = k(a,b) - 128;
   end
end

disp(A);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, if you have to subtract a fixed value it's better to do it as

```
M = M - 128;
```

It's faster.

You said you get `0` values instead of negative ones; it is likely due to the type of the matrix which is `unsigned` (i.e. the guys are just positive). A cast to general integer is necessary. Try:

```
M = int16(M) - 128;
```

To obtain the partition I propose the following, there can be more efficient ways, btw:

```
r = rand(256,256);            %// test case, substitute with your matrix M
[i j] = meshgrid(1:8:256);    %// lattice of indices      
idx = num2cell([ i(:) , j(:) ],2); %// cell version 

matr = cellfun( @(i) r(i(1):i(1)+7,i(2):i(2)+7), idx, 'UniformOutput',false); %// blocks
```

matr will contain all the sub-matrices in lexicographical order. e.g.

```
matr{2}

ans =

0.4026    0.3141    0.4164    0.5005    0.6952    0.1955    0.9803    0.5097
0.8186    0.9280    0.1737    0.6133    0.8562    0.7405    0.8766    0.0975
0.2704    0.8333    0.1892    0.7661    0.5168    0.3856    0.1432    0.9958
0.9973    0.8488    0.6937    0.2630    0.1004    0.5842    0.1844    0.5206
0.4052    0.0629    0.6982    0.1530    0.9234    0.1271    0.7317    0.3541
0.2984    0.3633    0.1510    0.0297    0.0225    0.7945    0.2925    0.0396
0.5097    0.0802    0.8744    0.1032    0.8523    0.6150    0.4845    0.5703
0.8635    0.0194    0.1879    0.5017    0.5297    0.6319    0.2406    0.5125
```

Explanation: In matlab you can efficiently operate on matrices and slices of them. For instance, you can easily copy submatrices, e.g. the first 8x8 matrix is

```
  sub = M(1:8,1:8);
```

You want all the submatrices, thus you need kind of a lattice of indices to get

```
  sub_ij = M(1+8*(i-1) : 7 * 8*(i-1) , 1+8*(j-1) : 7 * 8*(j-1))
```

i.e. you need the lattice

```
  (1+8*(i-1) : 7 * 8*(i-1) , 1+8*(j-1) : 7 * 8*(j-1))   % // for all i,j
```

you can use `meshgrid` for that.

Finally you have to cut off the pieces, that is what the last two instruction do. particularly the first one generates the indices (try `idx{1}`,...), and the second one generates the submatrices (try `matr{1}`,...).

Comment: One of my 8x8 matrix is                                                 91   93   93   95   94   92   96   97
   93   95   94   94   94   93   95  100
   93   94   94   92   95   97   95   99
   94   95   94   94   98   99   97   96
   92   94   94   94   97   98   98  101
   93   93   91   94   95   96  102  104
   92   91   92   93   96   95  101  101
   92   94   92   90   92   97   99  100                              if i use M = M-128 then I get 0 for all the elements                     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0

Comment: I am sorry i am not getting your last two lines of code idx = num2cell([ i(:) , j(:) ],2); %// cell version 

matr = cellfun( @(i) r(i(1):i(1)+7,i(2):i(2)+7), idx, 'UniformOutput',false); %//   I have also got error while using it

Comment: @sazib, I am extending the answer.

Comment: @sazib, nice, but glad to help! You may want to consider to accept the answer using the tick symbol at the left hand side.

Comment: for m=1:32
       A = int16(matr{m})-128;
end

If I want access the matrices after subtraction what do i have to do? is the last for loop is ok? I want to pass each matrix into a function. like dct()

Answer (score 0):

Hope this [code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/33103) helps you. It has 16x16 image to divide into 4x4 blocks. You may change the value and get the required output as you like.